# Enabling more resolutions on Sony Vaio

Tags: resolution, sony-vaio, ultrabook

My new Ultrabook comes with three screen resolutions:

- 1920x1080
- 1280x1024
- 1024x768.

1920x1080 is ridiculous on a 13.3" monitor and it's hurting my eyes trying to read small text. The other two resolutions are 4:3, meaning they only use up half of the screen (and look far too zoomed in). Ideally I'd like to be able to use 1366x768. Is there any way I can "unlock" this resolution somehow?

The GPU is Intel HD Graphics 4000, if that helps!

**Update:** I'm able to get it to 1360x768 by plugging in another monitor through HDMI. If I select "Duplicate These Displays" the 1360x768 of the monitor becomes available on the ultrabook.

However this is the only option I'm able to select which allows for this, meaning I can never have dual monitors set up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why get a laptop with a nice high-resolution screen and then make it scale up the image? It seems like a waste of a very nice screen.

Rather than scaling the resolution, you could just [change Windows' DPI settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-screen-text-larger-smaller#make-screen-text-larger-smaller=windows-7). In the display properties window, and then click on "Make text and other items larger or smaller". From there, you can scale up to 125% or 150% of the normal size. This will render fonts and windows at a larger size, without blurring the screen the way decreasing the resolution does.

[image: Windows DPI settings]

Once Windows 8.1 is released this fall, you'll get even better high-DPI display support. This is one of the major changes that is coming in Windows 8.1, and should make support for large text on a high-res display much simpler.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually gone with this for now (accidentally stumbled across it about an hour ago - should have posted really!). It is a shame to have to increase the font size though as you mention, but the issue I was having is that the letters were just far too small. In fact, here is a [picture I took](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/58924_10201449288775199_1360741158_n.jpg) - the coin I'm holding is a British 5p which is approximately 1cm in diameter. As you can see, each letter was only around 1x1mm, which is far too small.

Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed the graphics cards driver?

Often more screen resolutions are detected when you install it.

Comment: Yes, the driver has been customized by Sony too, so I can't update it through the Intel site.